# gpiozero and signal

Tags: gpiozero, signal

My python script waits for motion (with gpiozero MotionSensor wait_for_motion()) most of the time. But it also needs to react to SIGUSR1. The problem is: when SIGUSR1 is received wait_for_motion() is triggered. I have tried to put together a test case with the relevant parts of my script:

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor, DigitalOutputDevice
import signal

mwms = MotionSensor(4, pull_up=True)
foco1 = DigitalOutputDevice(17, initial_value=False)
foco2 = DigitalOutputDevice(18, initial_value=False)

def foto():
  foco1.on()
  foco2.on()
  print("foto")
  foco1.off()
  foco2.off()

def signal_1(signalNumber, frame):
  foto()
  return

if __name__ == '__main__':
  signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_1)

while True:
  try:
    mwms.wait_for_motion()
    print("Motion detected", flush=True)
    mwms.wait_for_no_motion()
    print("No motion", flush=True)

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nKeyBInt')
    break
  except:
    print('\nError')
    break
```

When SIGUSR1 is received the function foto() is executed correctly but mwms.wait_for_motion() ends and "Motion detected" and "No motion"  are printed.

Edit: As per @Milliways answer.
Regarding the slow code: I do not use print, that is only for the test case, I use raspistill, so it would be even slower :-)
I will try to figure out how to shorten the interrupt routine... Regarding the button: it is a web server that sends the signal, I do not know how to better communicate to the python script that it should execute the "foto" function.
I had two separate python scripts before, one for the motion-sensor and the other as the web server cgi, but it looks like a bad idea to have two independent scripts dealing with GPIO, is not it?

Comment: this may help ... section 2.18 ... https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sure, I have read those recipes.

Comment: if you truly read them, then why are you not using `when_motion`?

Comment: I used the gpiozero documentation:https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected - `signal` operates on the main thread.

`wait_for_motion()` - or ANY wait_for is poor practice as it blocks the main thread.

You would be better to use `.when_motion` or a callback https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#motion-sensor

You would be better to use the Button class and a `button.when_pressed` callback rather than `signal` to call `foto` and DO NOT include slow code e.g. print in interrupt routines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know signal operates on the main thread. I have only the main thread do not I? I will try pause() instead of wait_for_motion, but I am afraid signal also ends the pause.

Comment: I edited the first post to better clarify the environment. Thanks again.